# Could Mark Rober be liable if damage occurred due to his holiday prank on package thieves?

Tags: united-states, liability, hypothetical

For several years YouTuber Mark Rober has posted videos where he builds a device that can record video, play sounds, flash lights, spray fart spray, and shoot glitter when opened. He puts them in packages that are disguised as desirable expensive electronics and leaves them out on porches as if they are deliveries. People steal them and when they open them they automatically start performing the aforementioned functions.

In [this year's video](https://youtu.be/3c584TGG7jQ?t=551) someone opens the package while driving so it occurred to me that could easily cause injury or damage if a driver lost control of their car as a result of the glitter bomb.

So if someone stole one of these packages and was injured or caused damage in conjunction with these glitter bombs, is it conceivable that Mark Rober could be held legally accountable or even criminally liable?

I'm just curious from a legal perspective. I am not associated with him in any way nor do I plan on doing anything similar. I also only ever seen this in YouTube videos and have never been the victim of anything like this. I assume (since he's a smart guy) that he wouldn't do it if there was a big legal risk for him. Practically speaking it would presumably have to be a pretty severe accident for anything to happen since the complainant would have to admit to theft and pay for legal representation.

I found a couple questions here relating to glitter bombs but they seem a bit different than this situation (and don't really have thorough answers).

- [What if someone put a non-lethal "bomb" im a package addressed to them to get back at a mail stealing thief](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33799/what-if-someone-put-a-non-lethal-bomb-im-a-package-addressed-to-them-to-get-ba/33806#33806)
- [Is it legal to mail a non-explosive "glitter bomb" to myself to dissuade a mail carrier from tampering with my packages?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57811/is-it-legal-to-mail-a-non-explosive-glitter-bomb-to-myself-to-dissuade-a-mail/57813#57813)

Comment: "the complainant would have to admit to theft": Not necessarily - if the thief crashed into an innocent driver, that driver could potentially sue Rober without admitting to anything.  And they wouldn't necessarily have to "pay for legal representation"; the driver collects on their insurance, and the insurer (who has plenty of staff lawyers) sues Rober on the injured driver's behalf.

Comment: That's a good point

Comment: I suppose regardless of whether Mark would win or lose this case it could still be an expensive legal situation for him.